# JAWS 2024 Need to remove word "region" while getting region names

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, accessibility-api

I am working in JAWS 2024, I have created documents regions with name "Question" and "Exhibit". While using shortcut key (insert+alt+r) it is showing the name like "Question region" and "Exhibit region"  attaching me code snippet.

`specifyRegion: function (){ var questSpan = '<span id= "Question" style="display: none">Question</span>'; var exhibitSpan = '<span id= "Exhibit" style="display: none">Exhibit</span>'; $("#splitItem").append(questSpan); $("#splitItem").attr("role","region"); $("#splitItem").attr("aria-labelledby","Question"); $("#splitItemReference").append(exhibitSpan); $("#splitItemReference").attr("role","region"); $("#splitItemReference").attr("aria-labelledby","Exhibit"); }`

1.I have tried replacing "region" role with "" in attributes.
2.I have tried giving role as customised name like "abc" in place of "region" then that is not
reflecting the name in JAWS.
3.Tried with all the region names in which are mentioned in freedom scientific website.

https://support.freedomscientific.com/Content/Documents/Other/JAWS-ARIA-Support.doc

Referred this link and tried all the roles but nothing works for me.

Also i have tried following codepen example, attaching the link below.

https://codepen.io/Himanshu-Suyal/pen/ZEPQvYj

Could someone please assist me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to change Jaws correct behaviour of announcing regions as such? Is there a use case behind that? Are you a regular Jaws user or simply testing with Jaws?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I have created customised regions and I want JAWS to pronounce only those region names but in my case it is pronouncing region name along with region behind that region name. Let suppose I have "abc" as region name. then it is pronouncing "abc region". I want only "abc" to be pronounced.

Comment: Well sorry, this is how regions are announced. Period. Maybe a region is not really what you are looking for?